# No such file or directory when exporting function from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

src/test.js

```
module.exports.test = function() {
    const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
    console.log(readFileSync('test.txt', 'utf8').toString())
}
```

index.js

```
const { test } = require('./src/test.js');
test();
```

Which results in No such file or directory. Does `module.exports` or `exports` not work when requiring files in another directory?

Comment: You probably need `./src/text.txt` as path instead. (provided it said "test.txt" in the error message, not "test.js")

Comment: @ChrisG `test.txt` is in the same directory as `test.js`. `index.js` is not in the same directory... which is why i'm getting this issue. But I was wondering if theres a way to do this properly without having to move files

Comment: You don't? Cause it does. I tested your code and using `./src/text.txt` fixes it.

Comment: @ChrisG Oh, my bad. *face palm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do something like this:

```
readFileSync('test.txt', 'utf8')
```

that attempts to read `test.txt` from the current working directory.  That current working directory is determined by how the main program got started and what the current working directory was when the program was launched.  It will have nothing at all to do with the directory your `src/test.js` module is in.

So, if `test.txt` is inside the same directory as your `src/test.js` and you want to read it from there, then you need to manually build a path that references your module's directory.  To do that, you can use `__dirname` which is a special variable set for each module that points to the directory the module is in.

In this case, you can do this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports.test = function() {
    const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
    console.log(readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'test.txt'), 'utf8').toString())
}
```

And, that will reliably read `test.txt` from your module's directory.